# Richeditbox in UWP image not displayed properly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

[1]I'm working on a UWP using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version

I created a blank project, added a smile images in gridview and RichEditBox. I'm trying to insert an image in RichEditBox from local resources, but the smile images are blur in richeditbox.

Here is the code behind:

```
private async void SmileGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/"e.ClickedItem.ToString()+".png");
    StorageFile imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
    using (IRandomAccessStream rs =  await imageFile.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        box.Document.Selection.InsertImage(64, 64, 0, VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, "img", rs);
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml:

```
<RichEditBox Name="box" Height="200"/>
```

What could be the problem here? What's the correct way to do this?

please find some emoji images [https://1drv.ms/u/s!Audloz_YsRMugvw7WO62uhNsWzSlrA]

Comment: What's the image you are using? I'd suggest you check the dimensions of your image file and then insert the image with same dimensions of the  image file.

Comment: I using the image as 64*64 pixel png format, and  dimension I am inserting with the same.

Comment: Could you share some images so that we can reproduce your issue? Besides, what's the device you are using to test? Could you share the OS Build and also screen resolution and DPI level?

Comment: Resolution : 1440 x 2560 pixels (~518 ppi pixel density)
Device       : Microsoft_lumia_950_xl
OS Buid     : 10.0.14393.693

screen shot I already shared.